# If matrix A is symmetric and a certain condition holds then it is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

So the condition I am talking about is this one: $ a_{ii} > \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n} {|a_{ij}|} $

My idea for the proof would be:

Since the matrix is symmetric then I can diagonilize it and get a matrix where all the eigenvalues are represented by the values in the diagonal. Since the operations that lead to the diaagonalized matrix are all linear, I can say that for this matrix the condition $ a_{ii} > \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}{|a_{ij}|} $ still holds. The condition then can be also rewritten as $ a_{ii} - \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}{|a_{ij}|} > 0 $. Now in the diagonalized matrix it holds that $ \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n} {|a_{ij}|} = 0 $ which leads to $ a_{ii} > 0 $ which means that the eigenvalues are positive. This means that the matrix is positive definite.

Is my proof correct?

Thanks for any tips/help

Answer (score 1):

> Since the operations that lead to the diaagonalized matrix are all linear, I can say that for this matrix the condition $ a_{ii} > \sum_{j=1,i\neq j}^{n}{|a_{ij}|} $ still holds.

This sentence is vague and mathematically meaningless at best and false at worse:

The operation that maps $a_{ii}$ to $0$ and all other values $a_{ij}$ to themselves is linear, but it does not preserve your property.

---

For a better version of the proof, have you heard of Gerschgorin circles?

Comment: I saw when googling the problem, but thought that it could be done easier

Comment: There is no easier argument than the Gershgorin circle theorem, as that implies directly from the given inequalities that all eigenvalues have positive real part. And since the matrix is symmetric...